# conditional :for after a :when (in loop macro)

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to bind a variable inside a LOOP macro, but only conditionally.

Example:

```lisp
(loop :for (num div) :in '((1 2) (4 2) (3 0) (1 4))
      :when (/= 0 div)
      :for res = (/ num div)
      :collect num
      :do (format T "~A divided by ~A = ~A~%" num div res))
```

This doesn't work as written:

```
:FOR does not introduce a LOOP clause that can follow WHEN.
current LOOP context: :FOR RES.
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

Is there a way to do this inside a single loop call? Any solutions I can think of, involve breaking out of the loop somehow which has considerable drawbacks. Among others you lose access to the loop context (:collect etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with `loop`.  You can work around it as below if you have to use `loop`, although [coredump's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74603587/17026934) is better since a variable binding that is used exactly once might as well not exist.

```
(loop for (num div) in '((1 2) (4 2) (3 0) (1 4))
      for q? = (and (not (zerop div)) (/ num div))
      when q?
        collect num
        and do (format T "~A divided by ~A = ~A~%" num div q?))
```

However you can also just write Lisp rather than `loop`'s fragile pseudo-fortran.  The following uses Tim Bradshaw's [`collecting`](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#collecting-lists-forwards-and-accumulating-collecting) macro to factor value collection out of a looping construct (it also collects the quotient rather than numerator, so that there is some purpose to the binding):

```
(collecting
  (dolist (v '((1 2) (4 2) (3 0) (1 4)))
    (destructuring-bind (numerator denominator) v
      (unless (zerop denominator)
        (let ((quotient (/ numerator denominator)))
          (collect quotient)
          (format T "~A divided by ~A = ~A~%" numerator denominator quotient))))))
```

If the combination of iteration and destructuring is something you do a lot, then (using, this time, [metatronic macros](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#metatronic-macros) to make things a little easier):

```
(defmacro/m destructuring-dolist ((ll list &optional (value 'nil)) &body forms)
  `(dolist (<v> ,list ,value)
     (destructuring-bind ,ll <v>
       ,@forms)))
```

And now

```
(collecting
  (destructuring-dolist ((numerator denominator) '((1 2) (4 2) (3 0) (1 4)))
    (unless (zerop denominator)
      (let ((quotient (/ numerator denominator)))
        (collect quotient)
        (format T "~A divided by ~A = ~A~%" numerator denominator quotient)))))
```

If you want the numerators *and* the quotients, well:

```
(with-collectors (numerator quotient)
  (destructuring-dolist ((numerator denominator) '((1 2) (4 2) (3 0) (1 4)))
    (unless (zerop denominator)
      (let ((quotient (/ numerator denominator)))
        (quotient quotient)
        (numerator numerator)
        (format T "~A divided by ~A = ~A~%" numerator denominator quotient)))))
```

And of course, if you want to, now you can rely on the fact that you actually have fully-fledged destructuring lambda lists rather than whatever `loop` supports:

```
(with-collectors (numerator quotient)
  (destructuring-dolist ((numerator denominator &aux
                                    (valid (not (zerop denominator)))
                                    (quotient (when valid (/ numerator denominator))))
                         '((1 2) (4 2) (3 0) (1 4)))
    (when valid
      (quotient quotient)
      (numerator numerator)
      (format T "~A divided by ~A = ~A~%" numerator denominator quotient))))
```

Comment: I see, but this is only true because numbers in lisp are truthy. If NIL happens to be a valid value in the domain (which in my actual case it can be), this would fail. I like this answer but I can't accept it because it relies on a hack specific to the simplified example. Thank you though!

Comment: @hraban: I have extended it to make clear that you can't bind in `loop` after conditionals and to offer some improved alternative constructs.

Comment: thanks ignis this is more info than anybody who tries to do this could hope for. 

Answer (score 4):

With the `loop` construct you can use `unless` with a positive test and use `let` inside the `do`, so that the variable is only bound when necessary (but here it is not strictly necessary as it is used only once):

```
(loop 
  for (num div) in '((1 2) (4 2) (3 0) (1 4))
  unless (= 0 div)
    collect num
    and do (let ((res (/ num div)))
             (format t "~a divided by ~a = ~a~%" num div res)))
```

Comment: This is a better `loop`-based answer than mine was.

Comment: @ignisvolens thanks, I edited a bit the wording now that you extended your answer